# What do the verb prefixes in "aborder/déborder" mean ?

Tags: verbes, étymologie

In this case of "aborder" and "déborder", the "a-" and "de-" seem to related to a direction. Is this generally so?

Are "a-" and "dé-" generally opposites?

Also, would the opposite of aborder be "abandonner" ? And is "aban-" a verb prefix too?

Comment: Did you look up those word in etymology dictionnaries (cnrtl, etymonline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1 a-

From what can be read at the entry for "*a-*", which is called more precisely a combining form (Fr : *élément formant*), this is not so; direction is one possibility but not the only one; there are four possibilities, including direction.

(*added numbers ([1°], …) are used so as to be able to refer to the part they apply to in the present section when that part is taken up in more detail afterwards (other sections)*)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a-)) [first of the two] **a-** Exprime une idée
>
> - de passage d'un état à un autre, ou d'attrib.,  [1°]
> - ou de **direction vers un lieu**, [2°]
> - ou de manière [3°]
> - ou encore, d'inchoativité. [4°]

Here is the category relative to place (Fr : *lieu, direction*)

> II.− Dans les [parasynthétiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasynth%C3%A8se) à base substantivale : idée d'attribution, de direction vers un lieu, de manière
> [2°] **II.B.** − Idée de lieu
> b) Verbes préfixés intrans. :
> ♦ alunir « aborder sur la lune »
> ♦ amerrir « se poser à la surface de la mer »
> ♦ apponter « se poser sur la plate-forme d'un porte-avions »
> ♦ atterrir « reprendre terre »

*A few verbs in the other categories so as to illustrate the difference*

> [1°] **II.A.** − Idée d'attribution. − Le substantif de base a valeur de complément d'objet :
> accoutumer « donner la coutume à ... »
> accréditer « donner l'autorité nécessaire à ... »
> affamer « donner faim à ..., faire souffrir de faim en privant de vivres »
> affiler « primitivement, donner le fil à un tranchant »

> [3°] **II.C.** − Idée de manière (« disposer, réunir en » + substantif de base)
> affourcher « primitivement, disposer en fourche »
> aligner « mettre en ligne »
> amasser « réunir en quantités considérables »

> [4°] **III.** − Dans les dérivés de verbes : idée d'inchoativité de l'action
> **A.** −
> arranger. ,,... ranger signifie « mettre à sa place »; et arranger « créer, assigner aux choses des places convenables »`` (Laf. 1861, p. 131), c.-à-d. « ranger pour la première fois, établir la combinaison qui donne à un ensemble de choses leur place ». De même, a- suggère l'inchoativité dans :
> aposter « poster qqn dans un endroit déterminé »
> assigner « indiquer la place d'une chose »
> **B.** − apercevoir. […] **C.** − apparaître. − […]

### 2 dé-

The idea of direction is related to one of the concepts expressed by the combining form "*dé*"; however it is not really part of this form; this is the idea of *remoteness* (Fr : *éloignement*)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9-)) Préf. issu du préf. lat. dis-, formateur de nombreux termes composés, notamment de verbes, servant à modifier le sens du terme primitif en exprimant l'éloignement, la privation, la cessation, la négation, la destruction de qqc., l'action ou l'état contraire, inverse.
> [ …]
> décélérer/accélérer
> […]
> déborder/aborder [sens différents]
> […]

### 3 Conclusion

It can be seen from **2** that the two prefixes can have opposite meaning, but this is not generally so, and in particular it can be seen also from **2** that the meanings for "aborder" and "déborder" are not opposite but simply different.

The idea is that of "going towards" for "aborder".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aborder)) Achever un mouvement d'approche vers quelque chose ou quelqu'un

For  "déborder" is that of "going over". Although there is an idea of direction implied (as in "la rivière déborde") it is not expressed, not central.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9border))
>
> 1. [Gén. un cours d'eau] Dépasser brusquement les bords de son lit et répandre ses eaux. […]
> 2. [Le suj. désigne le contenu liquide] Dépasser les bords de son contenant et se répandre.[…]
>    A.− Franchir, dépasser le bord de quelque chose.[…]
> 3. Dépasser le(s) bord(s) d'une autre chose, des objets environnants.
>    […]

---

"Aban-" is not a prefix. No, the opposite of "aborder" cannot be "abandonner", but there is a similarity of concept that could induce one into thinking it is.

Comment: thanks, that link is interesting and has more examples of the a- prefix usage which I was initially looking for

Comment: @poseid In order to verify whether  a form "x…x" is a prefix it is only necessary to type "x…x-" in the "rechercher" box of the CNRTL page (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/). Occasionally, the prefix might be missing, but then it is a rare or from argot. Same thing for suffixes: start with a hyphen.